# How do I declare a constant in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I can't find this information from the internet, is it not possible to declare a final constant variable whose value will not change after first initialization?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I believe you can do something like:

```
readonly DATA=/usr/home/data/file.dat
```

You can also do:

```
declare -r var=123
```

Answer (score 26):

```sh
readonly FOO=bar
```

​​​​​

Answer (score 23):

In `bash` you can mark a variable read only by declaring it via the builtin `readonly` like so:

```
readonly CONSTVAR=value
```